# How to run equivalent of Mule studio "Export" in a script?

Tags: mule

I have the need to create a deployable ZIP archive from a script, much as the "Export" function does in Mule Studio. I'm expecting the ZIP to contain everything needed to deploy the app: JAR files, message flows, etc etc etc - again, just as Mule Studio Export does.

Is there a simple way to do this, or an example I can follow?

Comment: Both answers below are correct: pick one :)

Answer (score 4):

Maven is your best bet. Using the mule plugin for maven runnning `mvn package` will produce the deployable archive. More info on Mule and Maven here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Maven+with+Mule

There is also an ant plugin but don't use it myself. Some info here: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/building-mule-apps-with-ant/

Alternatively, you can read about the application deployment structure here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Application+Format , so in theory you can build this structure yourself. But I wouldn't advise it and would stick to Maven.

Answer (score 2):

Use Maven for building the app in jar/zip and deploy to the Mule standalone server automatically ... Make Sure your MULE_HOME is set to your standalone server in Environment variable ... and insert the following in your Maven Script to build it in Jar/Zip and deploy to app folder of Mule Standalone directly :-

```
     <build>
    <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>>${project.basedir}/lib</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
          </resource>
        </resources>


            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration> <!-- This tag sets true/false to copy jar/zip file to Mule server app folder --> 
                        <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>YOUR_APPPLICATION_NAME</finalName>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                        <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${eclipsePluginVersion}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- by default download all sources when generating project files -->
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <classpathContainers>
                            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/${vmtype}/${jdkName}
                            </classpathContainer>
                        </classpathContainers>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

        <!--
                    make sure that MULE_HOME is set when building (required below when copying the
                    artifact to Mule's apps directory
                -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enforce</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <rules>
                                    <requireProperty>
                                        <property>env.MULE_HOME</property>
                                        <message>You must set MULE_HOME before installing the example.</message>
                                    </requireProperty>
                                </rules>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>


        <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>package-example</id>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
<!-- This tag automatically deploy jar/zip file to server -->
                                        <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.zip"
                                            todir="${env.MULE_HOME}/apps" overwrite="true"/>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
```